# How can I specify a different library jar for a sbt plugin dependency?

Tags: sbt

I'm using the sbt-scalariform plugin with sbt, which is built with a dependency on the default version of scalariform (mdr/scalariform).  I'd like it to use a different/forked version of scalariform (daniel-trinh/scalariform) for my project.

Is there a configuration I can use in sbt in my project to specify the version of scalariform I want or do I need to fork/build my own custom version of sbt-scalariform built against daniel-trinh/scalariform?

(I'm not worried about compatibility between the two versions of sbt-scalariform.  sbt-scalariform is really just a wrapper.)

I can add dependencies to my project but that's for my compiled code, not the build process itself, right (Build.scala in my case)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
addSbtPlugin(org % name % version exclude (scalariformorg, scalariform)) 
libraryDependencies += scalariformorg % scalariformorg % version
```

Fill in the fields as appropriate for what you want to replace. This goes into `project/plugins.sbt`